# Is there a punishment for disgracing our prophets/sages?

Tags: reward-punishment, current-events, navi-prophets, islam, chazal

In light of the recent [Charlie Hebdo incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Hebdo_shooting) with depictions of Mohammed (and others like), are there any punishments for derogatory depictions of our Jewish prophets and sages (be it in our times or times of yore)?

Comment: It is forbidden to make derogatory statements unwarranted against anyone. And against righteous people in particular, and talmidei chachamim. Not sure if there is a special rule for prophets as such.

Comment: unless it's Elisha and you call him a baldie. Then you get eaten by bears

Comment: @CashCow [II *Divrei HaYamim* 36:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b36.htm#16): ויהיו מלעבים במלאכי הא-להים ובוזים דבריו ומתעתעים בנבאיו עד עלות חמת ה' בעמו עד לאין מרפא. [*T'hillim* 105:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26a5.htm#15): אל תגעו במשיחי ולנביאי אל תרעו. Though *navi* could be interpreted broadly to include Torah scholars (e.g. [*Shabbos* 119b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=119b&format=text), ובנביאי אל תרעו אלו ת"ח).

Comment: Highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45629

Comment: Another point to ponder: Does it matter if it's a Jew or a Non-Jew who does the denigration? If it's like any other prohibition, for example eating non-kosher, one has some obligation of 'Areivus' to help a fellow Jew avoid sin, but a Non-Jew can eat and enjoy their cheeseburger.

Comment: And just to clarify what shouldn't need to be clarified: even if the Halachah does warrant some response to a sin, it most definitely does NOT give anyone the right or permission to take matters into their own hand, or start a murderous rampage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Talmud ([Sanhedrin 99b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=99b&format=pdf)) says that one who is *mevazeh* a Torah Sage has no place in the World to Come.

Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh Deah [334:43](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6910)) lists this as the first of 24 reasons why a person can be excommunicated, even after the Sage passed away. As discussed in the commentaries there, the Sage has to be of a certain stature for it to reach that point.

I think the reasonable translation of *mevazeh* is denigrate, or make something despised in people's eyes (compare with [Koheles 9:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16470#showrashi=true&v=16)).

Comment: +1 beat me to it. I was gonna plug siman 243 siff 6 & 7 though.

Comment: Just to be clear: nowadays (for whatever reasons) formal excommunication is rarely if ever implemented.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48568/excommunication-in-judaism